# Can I use Microsoft Makecode to programme Lego NXT bricks?

Tags: nxt, software

As a teacher, I only have access to Chromebooks and I cannot (IT will not let me) use Linux on them. I'm trying to use a text-based coding language to programme NXTs. I would use ROBOTC, but I cannot get it to run on my Chromebooks.

I also have about 32-35 students per class times four classes, so I cannot buy cheap Windows machines, because I'd need at least 15 to make this work well.

I want to use the JS feature in Microsoft Makecode, but I cannot find information on whether or not this will work. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Just heard from Microsoft, MakeCode only works with Lego EV3, NOT NXT.